# construct std::pair in-place in vector::emplace_back

Tags: c++11, move, emplace

I have a class A defined like bellow:

```
class A
{
public:
   A() = default;

   explicit A(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
   {
      std::cout << "construct" << std::endl;
   }

   A(const A& obj)
   {
      std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
      *this = obj;
   }

   A(const A&& obj)
   {
      std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
      *this = obj;
   }

   A& operator=(const A& obj)
   {
      std::cout << "copy operator" << std::endl;
      return *this;
   }

   A& operator=(const A&& obj)
   {
      std::cout << "move operator" << std::endl;
   }
};
```

I use the class like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<A, bool>> v;
v.emplace_back(A(0, 1), true);
```

The emplace_back has the following output:

```
construct
move
copy operator
```

My question is, is there any way to construct A of the pair in-place without calling the **move** and **copy operator**?

Comment: Same question for map: [c++ - How can you emplace directly a mapped value into an unordered_map? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68828864/how-can-you-emplace-directly-a-mapped-value-into-an-unordered-map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `std::pair` has this constructor:

> [cppreference/utility/pair/pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)
>
> ```
> template< class... Args1, class... Args2 >
> pair( std::piecewise_construct_t,
>       std::tuple<Args1...> first_args,
>       std::tuple<Args2...> second_args );
> ```
>
> Forwards the elements of `first_args` to the constructor of `firs`t and forwards the elements of `second_args` to the constructor of `second`. This is the only non-default constructor that can be used to create a pair of non-copyable non-movable types.

You can therefore invoke:

```
std::vector<std::pair<A, bool>> v;
v.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, 
               std::make_tuple(0, 1), 
               std::make_tuple(true));
```

Comment: Nice! That solved my problem. I saw that in the example of cppreference **std::forward_as_tuple** has been used, does it make any difference with **std::make_tuple** in this case?

Comment: `std::make_tuple` always creates a tuple owning its contents. `std::forward_as_tuple` creates a tuple of references. In your particular case it doesn't matter as we're dealing with primitive types.